# How to speed up GEO search in WordPress

Tags: mysql, latitude-longitude, wordpress

I'm using the "WP_GeoQuery" class, which extends WP_Query so we can search posts via a UK Postcode (lat and long co-ordinates). It's working very well but it's incredibly slow.

Are there any steps I can take when extending the WP_Query with the below code to speed up the MySQL requests?

```
class WP_GeoQuery extends WP_Query
    {
        private $_search_latitude = NULL;
        private $_search_longitude = NULL;
        private $_radius = NULL;

        /**
         * Constructor - adds necessary filters to extend Query hooks
         */
        public function __construct($args = array())
        {
            // Extract Latitude
            if(!empty($args['latitude'])) { $this->_search_latitude = $args['latitude']; }
            // Extract Longitude
            if(!empty($args['longitude'])) { $this->_search_longitude = $args['longitude']; }
            // Extract Longitude
            if(!empty($args['radius'])) { $this->_radius = $args['radius']; }
            // unset lat/long
            unset($args['latitude'], $args['longitude'], $args['radius']);

            // Extract Post type
            if(!empty($args['post_type'])) { $this->_post_type = $args['post_type']; }

            add_filter('posts_fields', array($this, 'posts_fields'), 10, 2);
            add_filter('posts_join', array($this, 'posts_join'), 10, 2);
            add_filter('posts_where', array($this, 'posts_where'), 10, 2);
            add_filter('posts_orderby', array($this, 'posts_orderby'), 10, 2);
            add_filter('posts_distinct', array($this, 'posts_distinct'), 10, 2);

            // Run query
            parent::query($args);

            // Remove filters so only WP_GeoQuery queries this way
            remove_filter('posts_fields', array($this, 'posts_fields'));
            remove_filter('posts_join', array($this, 'posts_join'));
            remove_filter('posts_where', array($this, 'posts_where'));
            remove_filter('posts_orderby', array($this, 'posts_orderby'));
            remove_filter('posts_distinct', array($this, 'posts_distinct'));

        } // END public function __construct($args = array())

        /**
         * Return only distinct results
         */
        function posts_distinct()
        {
            return "DISTINCT";
        } // END public function posts_distinct()

        /**
         * Selects the distance from a haversine formula
         */
        public function posts_fields($fields)
        {
            global $wpdb;

            if(!empty($this->_search_latitude) && !empty($this->_search_longitude))
            {
                $fields .= sprintf(", ( 3959 * acos(
                        cos( radians(%s) ) *
                        cos( radians( latitude.meta_value ) ) *
                        cos( radians( longitude.meta_value ) - radians(%s) ) +
                        sin( radians(%s) ) *
                        sin( radians( latitude.meta_value ) )
                    ) ) AS distance ", $this->_search_latitude, $this->_search_longitude, $this->_search_latitude);
            }

            $fields .= ", latitude.meta_value AS latitude ";
            $fields .= ", longitude.meta_value AS longitude ";
            $fields .= ", location.meta_value AS location ";

            return $fields;
        } // END public function posts_join($join, $query)

        /**
         * Makes joins as necessary in order to select lat/long metadata
         */
        public function posts_join($join, $query)
        {
            global $wpdb;

            $join .= " INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS latitude ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = latitude.post_id ";
            $join .= " INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS longitude ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = longitude.post_id ";
            $join .= " INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS location ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = location.post_id ";

            return $join;
        } // END public function posts_join($join, $query)

        /**
         * Adds where clauses to compliment joins
         */
        public function posts_where($where)
        {

            $where .= ' AND latitude.meta_key="postcode_lat" ';
            $where .= ' AND longitude.meta_key="postcode_lng" ';
            $where .= ' AND location.meta_key="individual_details_postcode" ';

            if(!empty($this->_search_latitude) && !empty($this->_search_longitude) && !empty($this->_radius))
            {
                if(is_numeric($this->_radius))
                {
                    $where .= sprintf(' HAVING distance <= %s ', $this->_radius);
                }
            }

            return $where;
        } // END public function posts_where($where)

        /**
         * Adds where clauses to compliment joins
         */
        public function posts_orderby($orderby)
        {
            if(!empty($this->_search_latitude) && !empty($this->_search_longitude))
            {
                $orderby = " distance ASC, " . $orderby;
            }

            return $orderby;
        } // END public function posts_orderby($orderby)
    }
```

Comment: How many posts  have lat / long values in post_meta in your WP installation? Dozens?  Hundreds? Tens of thousands?

Comment: Only two posts at the moment. This is currently in the testing phases. Although I'm experienced developing with WordPress my knowledge is lacking with MySQl optimisation, which I'm assuming is where the speed of this query has issues. The default WordPress search is very fast but as soon as I use this class that modifies the WP_Query it takes over a 1 minute to load even though there are only two post to query.

Comment: I've been thinking about your problem. It's very strange that a query for only two lat/long points takes so long. I wonder if you can access your MySQL instance with phpmyadmin or some other MySQL client *while the query is running,* retrieve the query text with `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`, and post the query text here.

Comment: How are you calling the search?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a solution to the extended WP_Query class but I have found an alternative solution.

The search was being called via a custom page with a call to the new WP_GeoQuery class instead of WP_Query.

There were only 2 posts for testing purposes but the search process was very slow. After some testing I managed to pin point the code that was slowing the process down. This was the  public "posts_fields" function in the original WP_GeoQuery class from my first post. This contained the Haversine formula.

I had originally thought it could be getting stuck when I queried Google to get the lat/long distances of the Postcode (UK) being searched. After some testing and even switching to the postcodes.io API (recommended by the way) this definitely didn't seem to be the problem and it was definitely within the WordPress query and pointing to the "posts_fields" function.

I carried on researching some plugins, looking for alternative ways to carry out the lat/long search. Lots of the Geo plugins available are very complex and difficult to dissect and isolate the code so I can use it within my plugin and with my own custom theme and search result pages.

I did eventually find a plugin to make this work though. It's a small plugin and allows me to use it's functions within my theme and solves the problem, as the search is now fast. The down side is that the plugin doesn't seem to be supported anymore and it hasn't been updated for 2 years. But it's working nicely. The plugin is the "GEO Data Store" - https://wordpress.org/plugins/geo-data-store/

So I no longer use a custom query class and instead use WP_Query in the following way with this plugin activated:

```
$sc_gds = new sc_GeoDataStore();
$ids = (array) $sc_gds->getPostIDsOfInRange( $post_type, $radius, $latitude, $longitude );

$args= array(
    'post__in'          => $ids,
    'posts_per_page'    => 10,
    'post_status'       => 'any',
    'post_type'         => $post_type
);

$new_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

So the plugin's "getPostIDsOfInRange" function gets all the post IDs that fall within the radius of the latitude and longitude given. We then put these IDs within the "post__in" parameter of the WP_Query and we achieve the goal. It works great.

Not the way I wanted to do it, as an extended WP_Query class seems like the best approach but this is the fastest solution I've found.

I hope this helps someone.